# How to get one xml report for multiple nightwatch folders/files?

Tags: javascript, xml, jenkins, ui-automation, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to generate report for my nightwatch tests to integrate it with jenkins. My tests directory looks something like this:

```
- tests
  - folder 1
  - folder 2
      - folder 2.1
  - folder 3
```

When using the nightwatch default reporter, I'm getting multiple xml reports for each files. Is there a way to get one xml report appended for all the folders&files so that I can easily integrate it on Jenkins using jUnit?

Comment: Did you find anything to consolidate the xml's or generate a single html file report ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have time to write one on your own, this repo can generate one for you (in html )
[nightwatch-html-reporter](https://github.com/jls/nightwatch-html-reporter)

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins absolutely supports multiple XML files. I was able to use this pattern to have Jenkins pull in all the XML files from Nightwatch and collect them together to report on tests passed/failed for a job:
`e2e/reports/**/*.xml,e2e/reports/*.xml`

You might need to adjust that slightly, depending on your directory structure.